# Time Limit for Task Queue in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I am using Task Queue in GAE for performing some background work for my application. I have come to know that there is a 10 minute time limit for a particular task. My concern is how do I test this thing in my local environment. I tried thread sleep but it didn't throw any exception as mentioned in google app engine docs. Also is this time limit is measured by CPU time or the actual time.

Thanks.

Comment: What you can accomplish in 10 minutes on your machine bears no resemblance to what you can accomplish in 10 minutes on the App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

The time is measured in wall clock time.  The development server doesn't enforce time limits, although it's unclear why you'd want to test it because it's unlikely your tests will perform the same as they will in production, so trying to guess how much you'll be able to accomplish in 10 minutes on the production servers by seeing how much you can accomplish in 10 minutes on the development server will fail horribly.

Comment: You might like to test your recovery mechanisms by forcing time-out failures at different points.

Comment: actually I wanted to know how can I make my application fail safe by catching the exception thrown as it goes beyond time limit. Do u know where should I catch that exception?

Comment: You can't catch it.  You are out of time, so there's nothing you can do.  You should perhaps try to periodially check how much time you have left.

Comment: @Luca There is a DeadlineExceededError that you can catch to deal with the situation. In Google examples they often show starting another task to continue the processing.

Answer (score 1):

For your development server, start a timer when a task is initiated. keep checking in your code if you reached 10 mins wall clock time. When you reach, throw a DeadlineExceededError. It would be better to have the try and except statements in the class handlers which call a particular function of your code.